# left outer join sql server sum duplicate

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a problem when linking 2 tables to get possible sum results of each one :

```
select cli.codigo, cli.nome, sum(isnull(det1.val_venda,0)) as Vendas_Mes1,
   sum(isnull(det2.val_venda,0)) as Vendas_Mes2
   from clientes cli
   right outer join facmovim fac1 on fac1.clinro=cli.codigo  and
                             fac1.ano='2012' and month(fac1.datemi) =12
   right outer join facmovdet det1 on det1.tipdoc=fac1.tipdoc and
                              det1.serie=fac1.serie and
                              det1.ano=fac1.ano and
                              det1.docnro=fac1.docnro and det1.tiporeg = 'A'
   right outer join facmovim fac2 on fac2.clinro=cli.codigo and
                             fac2.ano='2013' and month(fac2.datemi) =3
   right outer join facmovdet det2 on det2.tipdoc=fac2.tipdoc and
                              det2.serie=fac2.serie and
                              det2.ano=fac2.ano and
                              det2.docnro=fac2.docnro and det2.TipoReg = 'A'

    where cli.codigo = 1 
    group by cli.codigo, cli.nome
```

Table det1 has 2 records and table det2 as 3 records. The sum result of each table is being duplicated 5 times.
Can you help me solving this issue ?
Many thanks

Comment: Could you define That you need Duplicates Rows for Filter

Answer (score 0):

You can get Duplicates row from single table by this code, Please Try it

```
  with cte as
  (
  select *,rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by autoid order by id ) from tablename
  )
  select * from cte where rn>1
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not fan of duplicate sum without over clause in the same query.
I always have strange result.

Can you try something like this :

```
select cli.codigo, cli.nome, sum(isnull(det1.val_venda,0)) as Vendas_Mes1,
sum(isnull(det2.val_venda,0)) as Vendas_Mes2
from (
select cli.codigo, cli.nome, sum(isnull(det1.val_venda,0)) as Vendas_Mes1,
0 as Vendas_Mes2
from clientes cli
right outer join facmovim fac1 on fac1.clinro=cli.codigo  and
                          fac1.ano='2012' and month(fac1.datemi) =12
right outer join facmovdet det1 on det1.tipdoc=fac1.tipdoc and
                           det1.serie=fac1.serie and
                           det1.ano=fac1.ano and
                           det1.docnro=fac1.docnro and det1.tiporeg = 'A'
where cli.codigo = 1 
union all
select cli.codigo, cli.nome, 0 as Vendas_Mes1,
sum(isnull(det1.val_venda,0)) as Vendas_Mes2
from clientes cli
right outer join facmovim fac1 on fac1.clinro=cli.codigo  and
                          fac1.ano='2013' and month(fac1.datemi) =12
right outer join facmovdet det1 on det1.tipdoc=fac1.tipdoc and
                           det1.serie=fac1.serie and
                           det1.ano=fac1.ano and
                           det1.docnro=fac1.docnro and det1.tiporeg = 'A'
where cli.codigo = 1 
) p
group by cli.codigo, cli.nome
```

Union as not bad performance at all and it's more sure, especially if you are not joining same table but different to generate different sum.

In you case you could perhaps to have this too

```
select cli.codigo, cli.nome, sum(case when fac1.ano = '2012' then isnull(det1.val_venda,0), else 0 end) as Vendas_Mes1,
sum(case when fac1.ano = '2013' then isnull(det2.val_venda,0) else 0 end) as Vendas_Mes2
from clientes cli
right outer join facmovim fac1 on fac1.clinro=cli.codigo  and
                          month(fac1.datemi) =12
right outer join facmovdet det1 on det1.tipdoc=fac1.tipdoc and
                           det1.serie=fac1.serie and
                           det1.ano=fac1.ano and
                           det1.docnro=fac1.docnro and det1.tiporeg = 'A'
where cli.codigo = 1 
group by cli.codigo, cli.nome
```

My code are not complete, but the logic is inside :)